# Getting hasMany relationship data from hasOne relationship Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

New to Laravel and MVC so I'm a bit stuck and hoping I can get a solution from you.

I have 3 tables:
Users
Companies
Assets

These are all joined by pivot tables (I think that's the right term)
company_user (A company may belong to many users)
asset_user (A user may have many assets)
asset_company (A company may have many assets)

What I would like to do is get all assets for the current users company.

I manage to get the users ID. I then somehow need to use the ID to find out which company they belong to, and then retrieve all assets for that company.

I have setup the models as I think they should be. I just need to know how to get the relational data.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use eager loading :
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

In your case:

```
$user = User::with('compagny.assets')->find($user_id)->get();
```

Where compagny and assets are the relationship function names.

Comment: Thank You. after a bit of research and advice I found that my DB structure isn't ideal for what I am trying to do. This would be the correct solution though.

Comment: Don't user `get()`, use only `$user = User::with('compagny.assets')->find($user_id);`